# Firefox Jetpack display addon button next to adress bar

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have a chrome extension that I want to port to firefox. In chrome, my extension has a button on the right of the adress bar which displays a popup when it's clicked providing a livesearch interface.

Firefox Development seems to be a bit complicated coming from chrome, so ich picked the Jetpack SDK or "Addon-SDK" to take a first look.

Is it possible to display my addon icon next to the adress bar using Jetpack, or do I have to use this full feature monster SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People tend to use Erik Vold's toolbar module for this, see this older answer for details:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7670488/562145

Comment: In conjunction with your template on github this works great: https://github.com/canuckistani/toolbar-template

Comment: When using a widget, it is possible to bind the panels position to the widget using `panel: mypanel`. Can this also be done using the toolbar?